# How can I add a page's ID to its permalink using WP_Rewrite?

Tags: permalinks, pages, url-rewriting, slug

I have a client who is adamant that the permalink structure for pages must be along the lines of `postname/postid`, such as `test-page/7`.

I've gotten as far as adding the post name using `$wp_rewrite->page_structure` with the following code, which works fine.

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_page_rules' );

function custom_page_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . '%pagename%'; 
}
```

However, when I add `%post_id%`, it is not converted to the page's ID. Examination of the WP_Rewrite class reveals that there is no `%page_id%` placeholder. Is this possible to do and, if so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use any code for this.  You just need to:

1. Go to your /wp-admin/options-permalink.php page
2. Select the 'Custom Structure' and enter: `/%postname%/%post_id%/`
3. Then press the 'Save' button